# Jquery counting on multiple pages

Tags: jquery

Im trying to make multiple quizes that will keep track of each quiz on each page.

So, far i only have 1 counter which cant keep track of which page the quiz are answered.

All of my quizes are in the ID tag ="jquiz" so i only have to use one stylesheet. How would i implement mulitple counters to my code

edit: updated code

```
 $(".jquiz li ul li").click(function(){

    if (!($(this).parent("ul").hasClass("answered"))) {

        // removes unanswered class and adds answered class so they cannot change answer
        $(this).parent("ul").addClass("answered");

        // runs if they clicked the correct answer
        if ($(this).hasClass("correct")) {
            //adds one to quiz total correct tally
            count++;
             }


             //score check
            if ($('ul.answered').length == 3) {
            $('#page1mark').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#page1total').html('You got a '+count+' out of '+3+' on the page 1quiz.');
        }

        if ($('ul.answered').length == 6) {
            $('#page2mark').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#page2total').html('You got a '+count+' out of '+3+' on the page 2 quiz.');
        }

        if ($('ul.answered').length == howmanyquestions) {
            $('#jquizremarks').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#jquiztotal').html('You got a '+count+' out of '+howmanyquestions+' on the total quiz.');
        }
    }
}};


   //---------The html
        <!-- page1--->
    <ol class="jquiz"> //how do i add IDs to each class in a page?
         <li>
            <p>Cake is yum</p>
                 <ul>
                 <li class="correct">True</li>
                <li>False</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: Give them the *class* "quiz", not the *id*. Then give each quiz it's own unique id.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Seems reasonable enough.  It's worded awkwardly, but as soon as I read Ben's comment, it was clear what the OP needs.

Comment: Sorry, the quiz is in <ol id="quiz">, so how would i change this to a class?

Comment: Thanks. i changed the CSS to classes and it now displays in a class . I just need to add in ID's, how would i go about doing this/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not have two html elements with the same ID. So, to do what you want the html elements should be of same classes with differents IDs, so:

1. Replace `id="jquiz"` in `ol` element for `class="jquiz"`
2. Change the jquery selector used for count how many questions exists; from `$("#jquiz > li")` to `$(".jquiz > li")`
3. Finally change the jquery selector that set the click handler; from `$("#jquiz li ul li")` to `$(".jquiz li ul li")`

Comment: `if ($(this).hasClass("correct")) 
   `{
    `if ($("#page1"))
     count1++;
    `if ($("#page2"))
     count2++;
       }`

Comment: That is what i have for my counter. but it doesnt seem to work :(. `<ol id="page2" class="jquiz">

Comment: @user1281921 the jquery objects always exists, so event if they don't match any elements with a selector, the test `if ( $('something') )` will always be true, you must check the `length` of jquery object and the value will be the number of matched elements..